# Regex to extract class names and id's

Tags: python, regex

How to exract each classname from `$('.lOffer-account-dropdown .name a')` using python. I want each of the classes `.lOffer-account-dropdown` and `.name` seperately. I would also like to extract id eg. `$('#main')`. Notice that classes and id are surrounded by `$(' ')`. Thnx.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a regex based approach using `re.findall` along with a list comprehension:

```py
inp = "$('.lOffer-account-dropdown .name a') $('.blah-blah-blah .loc p')"
output = re.findall(r"\$\('(.*?)'\)", inp)
output = [[y for y in x.split(' ') if y.startswith('.') or y.startswith('#')] for x in output]
print(output)  # [['.lOffer-account-dropdown', '.name'],
               #  ['.blah-blah-blah', '.loc']]
```

The call to `re.findall` generates a list containing the inner classes.  Then, we generate a list of lists of all classes for each classname using a list comprehension.

Comment: Can I find each classnames in one regex instead of splitting?

Comment: @ZuhairAbid You are trying to extract class names from nested content, and I don't know of a way to do this using a single regex.  In any case, I have updated to only capture class names starting with `.` or `#`.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Another question please.. Is there any way of doing a regex over regex. Like `re.compile().compile()` / `re.match()/match()`

Comment: I don't know what you mean, but you may certainly chain regex calls, e.g. by feeding the string output from one into another, etc.